# Laravel pass ID back from controller to view via redirect with errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

How can I pass $id back from controller to the same view when update is failed and error is trigerred.

I have view which prints all items from database and also adds edit button to each of the items which triggers modal popup window.

```
@for ($i =0; $i < count($inventory); $i++)

                     <tr>

                       <td> {{ $inventory[$i]->name }} </td>
                        <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{ $inventory[$i]->id }}">
                          Edit
                        </button>
```

After editting all the data are passed to route via form

```
<form action="/updateInventory/{{$inventory[$i]->id}}" method="post">
```

Then it goes to my controller which validates input and then inserts input into database.

```
public function update(Request $req,$id)

{
    $this->validate($req, [
        'name'=> 'min:2'
        ]);
    $inventory = inventory::find($id);
    $inventory->name = $req->input('name');
    $response = $inventory->save();


    if($response)
    {
        return redirect()->back()->with(['message'=>'gerai']);
    }


    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['error'=>'negerai']);
    //return redirect('/inventory');

}
```

But if input doesn't pass validation I'm printing error like that.

```
@include ('partials.notice')

                    @if($errors->any())

                    <script>
                        $(function() {
                            $('#myModal{{$id}}').modal('show');
                        });
                        </script>
                    @endif
```

How can I pass $id of element I just edited from controller back to the same view so when @if($errors->any()) triggers I can popup my modal $('#myModal{{$id}}').modal('show'); with element I wanted to edit.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel you can flash data into the Session. In your example you can do something similar to:

```
$request->session()->flash('idOfError', $id);
```

You can access it with :

```
               @if($errors->any())

                <script>
                    $(function() {
                        $('#myModal{{session()->get("idOfError")}}').modal('show');
                    });
                    </script>
                @endif
```

You can see more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#flash-data).

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried like that but my modal doesn't triggers at all like that. I looks like that ID isn't being stored in session for some reason. I'm getting no errors, but pop up just doesnt show up. Just to be sure should I add $request->session()->flash('idOfError', $id); in my controller?

Comment: @BenasGasiūnas yes you should add the line to your controller, before the redirection. But the $id variable should have the id of the modal that you want to trigger.

Comment: I did like you said and it's not working. It's just like item in session disappears after redirection.